# How to search for a Java string in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to search for instances of a character sequence in a Java string using Eclipse.  Is there an easy way or regex to do this?

Example:
Search for `Eggs` should match

```
String str = "Eggs and toast."
```

and **not** match

```
Eggs e = new Eggs()
```

Comment: so your line should also contain ". Not to mention " should be before (and after) the searched word.

Comment: Correct, it needs to be a Java string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
\".*Eggs.*\"
```

Comment: I'd add the beginning and end of line `^.*\".*Eggs.*\".*$`

Comment: This one will probably fail on:
`new Eggs("Eggs \"Eggs").Eggs("\"")`. You'd probably have to lookup all "Eggs" and look through it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

- Under search menu (press ^H)
- Go to `File Search` tab
- check `Regular expression` radio button
- Enter text `".*?Eggs[^"]*"` in `Containing Text` field on top
- Click on Search button

Answer (score 3):

In general this is very hard because what you want to search for is not "regular" in the sense of "regular expression".

One of the answers you've had suggests:

```
\".*Eggs.*\"
```

which is pretty good, but will still match, for example,

```
System.out.println("There are " + new Eggs().count() + " eggs");
```

In general, there is not going to be a regular expression which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for delimited text using regex is dodgy, however this will basically hit your target (and not too many others):

```
".*Eggs.*"
```

Use Search > File > with regex with exactly this search term (ie including the quotes)

This will however also hit lines like this:

```
 x = "foo" + new Eggs() + "bar";
```

Also note that you don't need to delimit the double quote, because it's just a literal as far as regex is concerned